Error: Merge an unknown field of end-group tag, indicating that the corresponding start-group was missing
I am trying to consume Kafka messages using C# but getting an error:

Merge an unknown field of end-group tag, indicating that the corresponding start-group was missing.

When I try to save these incoming messages into a binary file it works for Python but not in C#.
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
My code:
using System;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Google.Protobuf;
using RequestCreatedEvent;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    var config = new ConsumerConfig {
        GroupId = "testcdm",
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest
    };

    using(var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder < Ignore, string > (config).Build()) {
        consumer.Subscribe("dest-topic");

        Console.WriteLine("Consumer started. Waiting for messages...");

        try {
            while (true) {
                var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                if (consumeResult != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {consumeResult.Message.Value}");

                    // Decoding Base64 data
                    byte[] decodedData = Convert.FromBase64String(consumeResult.Message.Value);

                    try {
                        // Deserializing the Protobuf message
                        var requestCreated = RequestCreated.Parser.ParseFrom(decodedData);

                        // Accessing fields from the Protobuf message
                        Console.WriteLine($"systemId: {requestCreated.Merchant.SystemId}");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Protobuf deserialization error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ConsumeException e) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected error: {e.Message}");
        } finally {
            consumer.Close();
        }
    }
  }
}

Error:

Output : Consumer started. Waiting for messages...
Received message:
ClcKJGY5ZjZkZDg5LTc3MWItNTExMy1hNzViLTE5NjRhYWQxOGFjOCACMisKDAiLho61BhDA84ipAhINRXVyb3BlL1p1cmljaBoMCIuGjrUGEMDziKkCOAFaCURhdGF0cmFuc2IrCgwIq76OtQYQwMPFmgISDUV1cm9wZS9adXJpY2gaDAirvo61BhDAw8WaAmoWCg4zNS4xNTcuMTg5LjIzMBIERWNvbXIUEhIyMTA3MTMxMjQ4MDczNTUzMzh6BgoERWNvbYIBEgoQCgNDSEYQAhkAAAAAAACuQIoBJDoiCiA3TEhYc2Nxd0FBRUFBQUdNN3A0bEpHdmdtZEJRQUZRT5IBRBIPCgt1c2VyX2RhdGFfMRIAEg8KC3VzZXJfZGF0YV8yEgASDwoLdXNlcl9kYXRhXzMSABIPCgt1c2VyX2RhdGFfNBIA
Protobuf deserialization error: Merge an unknown field of end-group tag, indicating that the corresponding start-group was missing.


The base64 message seems valid when decoded with https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/ and I can't see any obvious mistake in the code either. Group tags haven't been used in over a decade, so the error indicates corruption in the data. You could try making a minimum runnable example that has the base64 string hard-coded.
